# Reading Megillah when it's only Purim for the listener

Tags: halacha, purim, megillat-esther

Residents of a walled city and unwalled cities celebrate Purim on different days. May either of these people read the Megillah for the other on whatever day the listener needs to hear Megillah? Or does it need to be read by someone who is obligated in the mitzvah on that specific day?

Would one fulfill his listening obligation *bedi'eved* if this was done?

Comment: I thought it was about location, not individual (though I now see that the plans of the individual also matter https://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/halacha-hashkafa/all-about-the-mitzvah-of-megillah-megillah-4a-and-4b/2012/02/29/)

Comment: How many questions is this?

Comment: Now that large parts of Klal Yisrael have accepted the psak by R' Moshe and others that in she'as hadechak you can hear it over the phone, you can also ask about a case where it's Purim for both.  Avoiding differences between the night and day reading and date line complications: this year there was a 50 minute span where it was before sunset on the 14th in Anchorage, but after alos on the 15th in Jerusalem.  Could someone in one place have heard it from someone in the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pri Chadash Orach Chaim 688](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1584624115647&pagenum=510&book=147778) quotes a Yerushalmi that rules that a person from an unwalled city cannot read the *megillah* on behalf of an inhabitant of a walled city.

When it comes to the reverse situation, the Yerushalmi is unsure of what the ruling is. However, Pri Chadash rules (based on his understanding of the Bavli) that a person from a walled city cannot read the *megillah* on behalf of an inhabitant of a unwalled city.

However, Pri Megadim ([Mishbetzot Zahav 688:4](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1584623167494&pagenum=425&book=147778)) disagrees, and believes that in the case of a person from a walled city reading the *megillah* on behalf of an inhabitant of a unwalled city, he does fulfill his obligation, at least *ex post facto*.